# Working on a Browser Extension, and so I moved my JS from HTML to the JS file. Now, my localStorage.setItem isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox-addon-webextensions

I had an issue where when I would try to test my extension in Firefox using `web-ext run`, the CSS of the page would load, but none of my HTML would. I found out that this was because my HTML is loaded based on an `if else` statement in JavaScript, and because extensions don't like script tags in their HTML bodies, I was advised to move my JS into a JS file.

Now that I've done that, my initial HTML does load, but when I go to press the submit button to set data into `localStorage`, nothing happens. I think it has something to do with my JS functions being based on other functions that exist in the same file, but I've tried changing the order of the functions around to no success.

Here are the two(technically three) functions I'm dealing with currently:

```
function main() {
    if (localStorage.length == 0) {
        document.title = "Set up Memento Mori";
        document.getElementById("thisTab").innerHTML = 
        `<div class="container">
            <div class="title"><h3>Set up Memento Mori</h3></div>
            <form>
            <label for="birthDate">Enter your date of birth:</label>
            <input type="date" name="Birthdate"id="birthDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))"></input>
            <button type="button" id="button">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>`;
    } else {
        document.title = "Memento Mori";
        document.getElementById("thisTab").innerHTML = 
        `<div class="container">
            <div class="title"><h3>Memento Mori</h3></div>
            <div id="memento-lg"></div>
            <div id="memento-sm"></div>
            <div id="clock"></div>
            <button type="submit" id="clearDob">Reset DoB</button>
        </div>`;
        renderTimers();
    }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    main();
});

 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

var birthDate; 

if (localStorage.getItem("birthDate")) {
    birthDate = localStorage.getItem('birthDate');
} else {
    birthDate = new Date();
}

$("button").click(function(){
    var dob = $("birthDate").val();

    if (typeof dob !== null) {
    const birthdate = dob.split("-");
    var parsedDate = (birthdate[0]+"-"+birthdate[1]+"-"+birthdate[2]);
    console.log(parsedDate);
    console.log(dob);
    birthDate = parsedDate;
    localStorage.setItem("birthDate", birthDate);
    } 
});
```

My HTML is pretty basic, just a single div with a script tag referencing my JS file in both the `head` section and before my `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Currently what happens is this:

- `main` is registered to run at `DOMContentLoaded` event
- `$("button")` runs and doesn't find any buttons so the subsequent `.click()` does nothing
- the script finishes
- `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired and main() runs

Another problem:

- Extension pages are just files, there's no server serving them, so submitting a `<form>` without `action` simply reloads the page as if you pressed Ctrl-R hotkey.

The solution is simple:

- load the script at the end of html file so it runs when DOM is ready
- remove `DOMContentLoaded` stuff and just run main() immediately
- don't submit forms (remove `type="submit"`) or use event.preventDefault() inside the click listener for the submit button

popup.html:

```html
  <script src=popup.js></script>
</body>
```

popup.js:

```js
if (localStorage.length == 0) {
.............
} else {
.............
}
$("button").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // in case you want to use type="submit" for whatever reason
........
});
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution, but it pretty much lands me in the same place as usual.

1. When you say to add the JS script at the end of the HTML, do you mean before the closing body tag?
2. With your proposed changes, the console notified me that there's an uncaught typeerror: dob is undefined. dob is only defined inside the button click function and wasn't an issue when all of this JS was on my HTML page.

Comment: I don't know what your code is now so I can't help. I thought my answer clarifies what you did wrong and how to fix it but apparently I'm bad at writing. And yes, before the closing body tag as you can see in popup.html code in my answer...

Comment: BTW, do you use devtools debugger breakpoints? Thing is, it'd be trivial to debug the code this way.

Comment: I'll give that debugger in the devtools a try tomorrow, not sure how to use it though, it'll be my first time.

Comment: Here's my code in a codepen, for your reference, thanks a lot for your help up until now! https://codepen.io/mance-rah/pen/OJNZgEg

Comment: Ok, I updated it to the latest version - I thought I had before I sent it to you, my bad. 
There's not much different, I just removed the DOMContentLoaded part and the script tag in my HTML Head section.

Comment: You did everything correctly so whatever problems you observe were simply hidden by the old incorrect workflow. Good news: now you can handle them in devtools debugger.

Comment: so stumbling through the debugger setting some seemingly meaningful breakpoints, I see that my var brithDate is undefined throughout the whole process.  If I try to manually set it in the console using localStorage.setItem(), it still remains undefined.

Comment: `$("birthDate")` should be `$("#birthDate")` so like I said, it's a separate problem.

Comment: just wanted to let you know that I got everything to work and it was all thanks to you!